# Loading d3 bullet chart into a span

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I'm attempting to load a d3.js bullet chart into an existing svg object:

```
<span id='element'><svg class="elm_12"></svg></span>
```

and in the js:

```
var svg = d3.select(elementid)
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("svg")
          .attr("class", "bullet")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
          .call(chart);
```

I assume I can't add an svg element to an existing svg element. Any thoughts on the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to place this as a comment but there are simply too many code statements. What about this:

```
<span id='element'></span>
...

var svg = d3.select("#element")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("class", "bullet")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

svg
    .data(data)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .call(chart);
```

Comment: Awesome, this actually gets closer.

...but it looks like the reason (in the example given: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061961) for loading the svg at data load time is the creation of multiple svg elements on data load. 

Doing it in the way described above only loads the first svg element (as it's outside of the .enter() statement.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this was enough for me to figure it out - THANK YOU.

```
var svg = d3.select(elementid)
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("svg")
.attr("class", "bullet")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
.call(chart);
```